# Android reset Counter

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to reset counter.I have a TextView=TV and a  Button=Btn . I am writing here some important part of my code.

```
int Counter=1;

 TV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked"
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Counter--;
            if (Counter == 0) {
                TV.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    });

 Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            }
 };
```

Now what is the soluation that when i click on BTN i can get a one more chance for click

i know we inrease value of int counter but this is not correct soluation Because i want that TV is disabled after one click till button is not clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android incremented counters wont reset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489692/android-incremented-counters-wont-reset)

Comment: Please if Any soluation

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one

```
TV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked"
                ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TV.setEnabled(false);
      }
});

Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          TV.setEnabled(true);
        }
};
```

Comment: shows a red line under setEnable     TV.setEnable(true);